# Two instances of my Liferay service implementation module

Tags: liferay, osgi, liferay-7

I wrote a module that defines a service:

```
public interface TranslationService {
    // a method.
}
```

... a module that implements the service:

```
@Component(
    immediate = true,
    configurationPid = "my.TranslationConfiguration"
)
public class TranslationServiceImpl implements TranslationService {

    log.info("Constructor " + getClass().getName()
             + " " + System.identityHashCode(this));

    @Activate
    @Modified
    protected void activate(Map<String, Object> properties) {
        log.info("Configuring " + translationService.getClass().getName()
                 + " " + System.identityHashCode(this));
        configuration = ConfigurableUtil.createConfigurable(
            TranslationConfiguration.class, properties);
}

    // an implementation of the method.
}
```

with its service activator:

```
public class ServiceActivator implements BundleActivator {

    private ServiceRegistration registration;

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        registration = context.registerService(TranslationService.class.getName(), new TranslationServiceImpl(), null);
    }

    [...]
}
```

... and a module that uses the service:

```
@Component(
    immediate = true,
    configurationPid = [...]
    service = Portlet.class
)
public class TranslationPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

    @Reference(unbind = "-")
    protected void setTranslationService(TranslationService translationService) {
        log.info("Using " + translationService.getClass().getName()
               + " " + System.identityHashCode(translationService));
        this.translationService = translationService;
    }

    private TranslationService translationService;
}
```

## Log

Log when I start (via Gogo Shell) the API and implementation modules:

```
Constructor my.TranslationServiceImpl 606817095
Service registered.
STARTED my.impl_1.0.0 [538]
Constructor my.TranslationServiceImpl 362465287
Configuring my.TranslationServiceImpl 362465287
```

Then when I start (via Gogo Shell) the using module:

```
STARTED my.app_1.0.0 [558]
Using my.TranslationServiceImpl 606817095
```

## Question

Why are two instances being used?
How to make all modules use the same instance of my service implementation?

## Details

Stacktraces of the two times the implementation constructor is called:

```
my.TranslationServiceImpl.<init>(TranslationServiceImpl.java:56)
my.ServiceActivator.start(ServiceActivator.java:24)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:951)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:328)
org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:566)
org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:402)
org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Basic.start(Basic.java:729)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:137)
```

Then:

```
my.TranslationServiceImpl.<init>(TranslationServiceImpl.java:56)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createImplementationObject(SingleComponentManager.java:236)
org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createComponent(SingleComponentManager.java:108)
org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService(SingleComponentManager.java:906)
org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getServiceInternal(SingleComponentManager.java:879)
org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:748)
org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enableInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:674)
org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(AbstractComponentManager.java:429)
org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ConfigurableComponentHolder.enableComponents(ConfigurableComponentHolder.java:657)
org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialEnable(BundleComponentActivator.java:341)
org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:403)
org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.access$200(Activator.java:54)
org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator$ScrExtension.start(Activator.java:278)
org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:259)
org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:232)
org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:482)
org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:1)
org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232)
org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:444)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:905)
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:165)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:75)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:67)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:102)
org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:461)
org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:452)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:402)
org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Basic.start(Basic.java:729)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:137)
```

So its seems like I should not instantiate the implementation in the service activator? That's how it seems to be done in [this tutorial](http://proliferay.com/writing-your-first-osgi-service-in-liferay-7/) though.

Comment: That looks impossible. Do you ever see a line that says "Configuring my.TranslationServiceImpl 1451438505"?

Comment: Can you double-check with constructor-logging?

Comment: @NeilBartlett: I added more details, plus constructor logging. Also I realized that my service activator is probably causing the problem, but I am not sure how to change it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @OlafKock Good catch Olaf. The constructor logging reveals that he is explicitly instantiating his component class from a bundle activator. So it's pretty obvious why he's getting a second instance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a second instance of the component because you are explicitly creating it, on line 24 of `ServiceActivator.java`. This is revealed by the first stack trace that you posted.

Simply remove that line of code, and everything will be fine.

In fact you probably don't need ServiceActivator at all. I assume that it is the `BundleActivator` for your bundle? You do not need to write activators when using DS, because anything you can do in an activator can be done in a DS component, and much more besides. In fact my general recommendation is to never write bundle activators.

Comment: Oops I missed that fact that you posted the code for ServiceActivator.java. Yeah you definitely don't need that. Just delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Neil has found the answer, let me just add a few details:

As Neil said, a service activator is not needed, despite what suggests the tutorial I linked to in my question. Just delete it.

Obviously, also remove the `Bundle-Activator:` line from `bnd.bnd` otherwise you will get a `Bundle-Activator not found on the bundle class path nor in imports` error when deploying.

In place of the service activator, use that "DS" thing Neil talks about. It means Declarative Services, and is an OSGi technology that works with annotations. To use it, just add a `service =` instruction in the `@Component` annotation of your implementation class, with the implemented service (API)'s interface as a value. Example:

```
@Component(
    service = TranslationService.class,
    immediate = true,
    configurationPid = "my.TranslationConfiguration"
)
public class TranslationServiceImpl implements TranslationService {
```

Comment: Hey, I read the tutorial that you linked and it doesn't look very good. One of the problems we have in OSGi is that there are a million tutorials written by people who, frankly, need to study more before attempting to teach. But as a total beginner it's hard to tell which tutorials are good and which are junk. FWIW I don't think that the "proliferay.com" site has anything to do with Liferay, and probably infringes their trademark.